# Is ‘to start’ the same as ‘to start with’?

Tags: expressions

[image]

The highlighted phrase makes me confused. Does it mean first/initially or Do you native speakers say ‘start a melon’, that’s to say, the ‘start’ here is a transitive verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been suggested I write a full answer to this, rather than merely expand on incomplete and inaccurate statements in comments.

In this context, "to start" means "to start the meal with".

The writer is writing a shopping list (in a wordy and discursive way) for a semi-formal meal, and at the same time deciding upon what the food should be.

In this case, the melon would be served as a starter ("hors d'oeuvres"), the initial light course which commences the meal, and awakens the tastebuds for the more substantial main course which will follow.

It is a popular choice in Western (particularly English) dinner-parties to serve up melon as the "starter". Not all fruit is served up in this way, as a starter -- in most cases, fruit (prepared in a variety of ways) would be offered as a dessert.

This may arise from the fact that, when imported fruit became more common on the shelves of British supermarkets after the war, people picked up on it as "exotic" and "posh", and would present it at dinner-parties to impress their guests. As it is an excellent way to start a meal, melon remained popular.